# Conformation of Basic De Moivre Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Hello I am just wondering if my understanding of De Moivre formula is correct.

Say we want to solve $$(1+i)^{100}$$

then can we simply just do

$$(1+i)^{100}=\sqrt{2}^{100}((\cos(50\pi)+i\sin(50\pi))$$

Is that correct application? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost correct. To use De Moivre's formula you need to get the complex number into polar form (which you have clearly attempted to do). In this case we get $r=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$ and $\theta=\arctan(1/1)=\pi/4$. Hence $1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i(\pi/4)}$. Then applying De Moivre's theorem we get:

$$
\begin{split} (1+i)^{100}&=(\sqrt{2}e^{i(\pi/4)})^{100} \\ &=\sqrt{2}^{100}e^{i(25\pi)} \\ &=\sqrt{2}^{100}(\cos(25\pi)+i\sin(25\pi)) \end{split}
$$

Comment: Yes but we have i so why is it not $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: OH, never mind I see why, it is like x=1cos and y=1sin so that is how we get the angle. Thanks

Comment: For a complex number $a+bi$, you should think of it as lying on the plane at point $(a,b)$. The angle $\theta$ is the angle counter-clockwise from the $x$-axis and is given by $\theta=\arctan(b/a)$.